# Dangers of attempted self-correction of foot weight distribution issue?

Tags: posture, foot

When I stand normally I feel the bulk of my weight distributed under the big toe joint (the joint closest to the foot proper), and the inside of my heel.  I presume this is abnormal.  Also, I've had bunions and bunion surgery before, and I think that my weight is distributed like that may be the reason I previously developed bunions.  I have not had bunions for 10 years, after the surgery.

What I'm doing now is self-correction, by intentionally moving my ankles such that the weight feels more evenly distributed among the whole surface under the foot.  This is now a habit and I do it without thinking about it.

I haven't had any issues with this yet, with frequent and long running or just general daily walking.  Is this a bad habit I've gotten myself into, for any reason?

Comment: Seek medical help/therapy